# How to make a big holographic number?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to try to make a simple holographic graphic in Minecraft that shows a number, but bigger than the normal invisible Armour Stand's method, so it can be seen from a far distance away. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: I cannot write an answer at the moment, but you might want to check out [Asdjke's holograms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1B19JvX5TE).

Comment: @Lars I think this should be an answer.

Comment: @Mystery link only answers are discouraged, though. I'll try to write a proper answer later this evening.

Comment: @Mystery Asdjke's website seems to be down. He put the MCEdit filter up there, so that's a bit of a problem.

Comment: @Lars Strange... I remember browsing his site a few days ago.(not sure)

Comment: @Mystery I don't know. I guess, you could call it a "mystery". Sorry, just had to!

Comment: @TrivisionZero What is it you wish to accomplish with this?

Comment: @Jason_ It was just for a small Elytra map a long time ago, I no longer need to know. But people are still welcome to answer if anyone else needs this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly simple way to do this in comparison to the complex ways.  `MC Labs15` Created a hologram generator that is simple and fast to use.  This is a link to his video of this:

And here is the links to the generators:

Minecraft 1.9 Version: http://mclabs15.eu5.org/hologram

Minecraft 1.8 Version: http://mclabs15.eu5.org/hologram.html